# Python Multithreading - restart before thread has finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sqlite, python-multithreading

I'll try to condense this as much as possible. The general idea is I perform some actions on a sqlite3 database using threads (very minimum code sample is in the code below). The Thread() is always running.

Sometimes, the user has to stop the thread to delete objects from the sqlite3 table, and then turn it back on again (this switching happens with a GUI button associated with the global variable sched_var, that controls Run()- see code below).

The actual deleting from the sqlite database works fine. However, I figured out that if I re-start the thread before the most recent thread cycle has finished, it does not take into consideration the changes made into the database and keeps using the old information (i.e. keeps working on the deleted file as well). I saw that only if I wait for the last cycle to finish before I turn it back again (with the global variable), then it will consider the changes made to the database.

However, waiting for the thread cycle to finish is not applicable in practice, so I have to solve this problem so that the user can restart the thread safely.

I should add that the problem only happens when *deleting* entries from the sqlite table. Adding new entries does not seem to cause such a problem. Perhaps it is caching the information and only clears it out when the cycle is finished?

I have tried Lock() and t.join() and playing around with the overall code structure, but nothing works. I have been reading a lot about stopping threads, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this particular situation.

```
def Thread():
    ## connect to sql table, retrieve data, etc .. (omitted)
    for row in data:                   ##iterate through rows by accessing column(key in each row) 
        ## extract variables from sql table
        input_file = row['FileName']          
        output_dir = row['Destination']
        time_int= row['Time_Interval']
        t = threading.Thread(target = Run, args = (input_file, output_dir,time_int,)).start()

def Run(input_file, output_dir, time_int):
    while True:
        time.sleep(time_int) 
        ### do actions it should be doing (omitted) 
        if sched_var == False:          ## function stops
            break
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, just guess it's not a threading problem, it's a database commit policy problem --- you want to commit all the operations before you terminate a thread?

Comment: I think the changes are committed to the table itself, as the number of rows printed when I restart the thread again is as expected. If there is some deeper level of updating/commiting I don't know about?

Comment: Your code block didn't show enough information. Just suggest you add `connection.commit()` at every circle of loop.

Comment: @YangHG thank you, I think the commiting itself is working fine, I tested it with some print statements, and the problem only exists with deleting data, not adding. I think it has to do with beginning a new thread before the last cycle is finished, for example not clearing out cache or it just gets confused, I don't know :(